# How to mock constructors and destructor with gmock

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, googletest, googlemock

I need to count how many times constructors(default/copy/move) and destructor have been called. I use gmock. How can i check it?

EDIT: Thanks to Marko Popovic suggestion i will explain that i have for now. I have a class like this, and i want to mock it with gmock. How can i do this?

```
class A
{
public:
    static int m_calls_to_cons;

public:
    A( )    { m_calls_to_cons++; }
};

int A::m_calls_to_cons;
```

I use this class to check behavior of my container.

Comment: Would be nice to have some explanation for minus or close votes. Thanks.

Comment: Did not downvote but I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact that it is only two sentences and it is not clear what exactly do you want. What does gmock have to do with counting ctor/dtor calls? Please give more context so we can understand better.

Comment: It is not easy task, and really depends on your use case. I mean, you'd need to use some "workaround" to make this counting - but what kind of workaround you can use, depends on your usage. Please specify what are those objects - local, created from factory, injected?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes either. The request is incredibly obvious. The guy wants to count how many times constructors, destructors, etc. have been called.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must specify what you need. The way to do this is by defining interface class:

```
class SpecialFunctionsNotifier
{
public:
    virtual ~SpecialFunctionsNotifier() {}

    virtual void construct() = 0;
    virtual void destruct() = 0;
    virtual void copyConstruct() = 0;
    virtual void copyAssign() = 0;
};
```

So, you can make "default" null (meaning empty) object implemention:

```
class SpecialFunctionsNullNotifier : public SpecialFunctionsNotifier
{
public:
    virtual void construct() override {}
    virtual void destruct() override {}
    virtual void copyConstruct() override {}
    virtual void copyAssign() override {}
};
```

And, have `A` use of it:

```
class A
{
public:
    static SpecialFunctionsNullNotifier m_calls_to_cons_default;
    static SpecialFunctionsNotifier* m_calls_to_cons;

public:
    A( )    { m_calls_to_cons->construct(); }
};

SpecialFunctionsNullNotifier A::m_calls_to_cons_default;
SpecialFunctionsNotifier* A::m_calls_to_cons = &A::m_calls_to_cons_default;
```

Then, mocking this notifies is easy task:

```
class SpecialFunctionsNotifierMock : public SpecialFunctionsNotifier
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(construct, void());
    // ..
};
```

And in your tests, use in this way:

```
TEST(ACase, AConstructCount)
{

    SpecialFunctionsNotifierMock callToConsMock;
    A::m_calls_to_cons = &callToConsMock;
    EXPECT_CALL(callToConsMock, construct()).Times(100);
    A a[100];
    // remember to cleanup
    A::m_calls_to_cons = &A::m_calls_to_cons_default;
}
```

Comment: +1. That is nice trick, but hardly it will make code mo readable than just comparing A::m_calls_to_cons with some number. Probably for now i will not mock this class.

Comment: Also you can make virtual destructor protected, as you never delete from pointer to base class.

Comment: @Yola - regarding virtual destructor as protected. Regardless it will compile with current usage or not, it is not a good habit to stick classes to its current usage, thus preventing from using in other use cases.